# Minimize the number of timed intervals to submit AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a working solution to automatically refresh content on a web page by using the Javascript function:

```
window.setInterval(function()
{

 }, 1000);
```

But this creates a number of GET requests when viewing the development console:

[image: Multiple Get Requests]

Whereas in comparison to other websites which use a method of AJAX to refresh page content.. There is only one at the most 2 requests in the development console? So just by doing this, where have I gone wrong? Because I can see a possible downfall with the current solution.. The entire code:

```
 <script>
window.setInterval(function()
{
  $(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'Ajax/AjaxRecentEnteries.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
        {
        $('#output').empty();
            for (var i in rows)
            {
                var row = rows[i];          
                var id = row[0];
                var Title = row[1];
                var Cat = row[2]
                $('#output').append("<br>Page: <a href=Page.php?ID="+id+">"+Title+"</a>");
            } 
        } 
    });       
  });
 }, 1000);
  </script>
```

Comment: did you check something like singalr ? websockets ?

Comment: you can reduce the interval by using longpolling, or you can implement a solution using websockets. Do you really need it to update every second? or even every minute?

Comment: wrap your current `ajax` call in another `ajax` call's `success callback` in the first `ajax` check if there is new data (use some suitable and effective logic) to be loaded and on basis of the response trigger the `ajax` wrapped in the success callback

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior for an AJAX call because AJAX initiates a new "handshake" on every call.

Something like WebSockets would enable you to maintain a persistent connection with the server so that you may continuously exchange data at your leisure.

Same idea as writing a script to maintain an active connection to a DB on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Two simultaneous requests for one page at most is exactly as it should be (correct behaviour).

Try "websockets", "flashsockets" or "long polling" (depends on your requests to browser capability).